# “Thus ignoring” meaning of thus in text?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, adverbs

Shaping Identity in Eastern Europe and Russia: Soviet and Polish Accounts of ...

> Authors of survey histories were criticized for focusing on interclass as opposed to intraclass conflict **thus ignoring** the revolutionary role of the peasantry in the seventeenth century and erroneously labeling the Khmelnytsky uprising as a “ national bourgeois” revolution against Polish trade capitalism.* Particularly harsh was Skubytsky...

I am trying to detect the meaning of “thus” in this text, but with no hope.

I am trying to replace it with therefore or consequently. But it doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: It means: thereby ignoring, in that way ignoring. The first  part of the sentence is X and for that reason, or in that way ignores.

Answer (score 3):

**Thereby** is a good choice since it emphasizes that there was a decision (focusing on interclass conflict) and a result (ignoring the revolutionary ...).